# How are representations of SU(2) identified with non-intersecting curves in a disk? (Rumer-Teller-Weyl)

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, smooth-manifolds

Apparently (e.g. see bottom left of first column on p3 of [this manuscript](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0307511.pdf)) **the representations of $SU(2)$ can be identified with diagrams of non-intersecting curves (unoriented embedded $1$-manifolds) in a disk**. This is supposedly related to the Rumer-Teller-Weyl theorem. (Context: this is of significant importance to physicist, since the latter naturally arises when considering the braiding of particles in two-dimensional space. Hence this identification would explain why $SU(2)$ Chern-Simons theories are common tools to describe so-called topological phases of matter.)

Can anyone illuminate this connection between $SU(2)$ and curves in a disk? An intuitive understanding would be ideal.